# Alternative row color to div in css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I am trying to add alternative row color to div by using `nth-child(odd)`.

I need to add the alternative color for the div which has the class name `alternative_cls` but not to the div which has the different class name.

But the problem is it is not skipping the div with different class name, alternative color is applying including the different class named div also.

Here is the [**CODE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dfy59/2/)

What I want is

[image]

Comment: @PerfectDark updated the question. I want the output as shown in the image

Comment: hi i update your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/Dfy59/3/)

Comment: @jhunlio that is not what I want. I need to give the single class name. in short, alternative color should apply only to the .alternative_cls div, it shouldn't consider the .no_bg div.

Comment: The `nth-child` selector matches the nth child, regardless of element type or any associated class, of its parent.

Comment: None of the solutions below worked for you?

Comment: @abbood nope. actualy no_bg div can come n times in the flow not only one time So i need the dynamic solution to target only the divs with class name .alternative_cls

Comment: sorry you're right and I was wrong.. i did some more testing and updated my answer.. hope it works for you

Comment: if it didn't work for you please let me know why.. as i've spent quite a while on the discovery and the explanation

Comment: @Sowmya i think it's safe to say my answer is the correct one one this one

Answer (score 13):

here you go http://jsfiddle.net/Dfy59/6/

**explanation:**

by [definition](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) a css `n-th:child` selector

*matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent.*

so let's take your code for example (and remove the no_bg node first):

```
.alternative_cls:nth-child(odd){
    background:#ccc;
}
```

is applied like so:

```
<div class="alternative_cls"> <!-- alternative_cls(n)=1, odd so apply = (grey) -->
    ssf
</div>
<div class="alternative_cls"> <!-- alternative_cls(n)=2, even so don't apply = (transparent) -->
    ssf
</div>
<div class="alternative_cls"> <!-- alternative_cls(n)=3, odd so apply = (grey)-->
    ssf
</div>
<div class="alternative_cls"> <!-- alternative_cls(n)=4, even so don't apply = (transparent) -->
    ssf
</div>
..
etc
```

the confusion happens when you insert a div with a different class in between, when that happens, css still counts the intruder div as a sibling of the `.alternative_cls`, but then doesn't apply the css to it:

```
<div class="alternative_cls">  <!-- alternative_cls(n)=1, odd so apply = (grey) -->
    ssf
</div>
<div class="no_bg">  <!--alternative_cls(n)=2, but don't apply alternative_cls, just apply no_bg = (pink) -->
    ssf
</div>
<div class="alternative_cls">  <!-- n=3, odd so apply = (grey) NOTE: you'd expect the nth-child selector to skip the last node.. but it didn't, which caused the confusion -->
    ssf
</div>
<div class="alternative_cls"> <!-- n=2, even so don't apply = (transparent) -->
    ssf
</div>
<div class="alternative_cls">  <!-- n=3, odd so apply = (grey)-->
    ssf
</div>
<div class="alternative_cls">  <!-- n=4, even so don't apply = (transparent) -->
    ssf
</div>
```

the way I knew this is by looking at my chrome dev tools and playing around with the jquery selectors:

```
$('.alternative_cls:nth-child(1)')
```

returns

```
[<div class="alternative_cls">
    ssf
</div>]
```

but (**and this is the part that is counterintuitive**)

```
$('.alternative_cls:nth-child(2)')
```

returns

```
[]
```

you'd expect this selector to return the node immediately after the no_bg div.. **but it doesn't!**

continuing..

```
 $('.alternative_cls:nth-child(3)')
```

returns

```
[<div class="alternative_cls">
    ssf
</div>]
```

(I recommend you try this yourself for the concept to sink in)

so to go around this you simply set the css as

```
.alternative_cls{
    width:100%;
    height:60px
}
.alternative_cls:nth-child(1), .alternative_cls:nth-child(even){
    background:#ccc;
}
.no_bg{
     width:100%;
    height:60px;
    background:#f8d6d6
}
```

and this happens

```
<div class="alternative_cls">  <!-- n=1, apply the nth-child(1) rule = (grey) -->
    ssf
</div>
<div class="no_bg">   <!--alternative_cls(n)=2, but don't apply alternative_cls, just apply no_bg = (pink) -->
    ssf
</div>
<div class="alternative_cls">  <!-- n=3, odd, so don't apply any rule = (transparent)-->
    ssf
</div>
<div class="alternative_cls"> <!-- n=2, even so apply the nth-child(even) rule = (grey) -->
    ssf
</div>
<div class="alternative_cls">  <!-- n=3, odd, so don't apply any rule = (transparent)-->
    ssf
</div>
<div class="alternative_cls">  <!-- n=4, even so apply the nth-child(even) rule = (grey) -->
    ssf
</div>
```

i hope this makes it clear.. so with this knowledge you can continue to use the nth-child selector, you just have to account for this peculiarity

Comment: Its getting complicated :) Anyways your answers gives an idea to make it in another way. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: no probs man.. btw please share with us your final solution.. i'm curious.. i may even vote it up ;)

Comment: I have added an answer. Chk it

Comment: It's not all that complicated. If an element is not an even child of its parent, it's not `:nth-child(even)`. That's it. It doesn't matter what class it has or doesn't have.

Comment: Thanks for the endorsement @BoltClock..i take it that my answer is the correct one :p

Answer (score 3):

Is this working for what you need?:

```css
.alternative_cls:first-child,
.alternative_cls:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #ccc;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/earthdesigner/DWcHD/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I have moved the .no_bg div into the .alternative_cls, n ow it is working fine.

```
<div class="alternative_cls">
    ssf
    <div class="no_bg">
    ssf
</div>
</div>
<div class="alternative_cls">
    ssf
</div>
<div class="alternative_cls">
    ssf
</div>
<div class="alternative_cls">
    ssf
</div>
<div class="alternative_cls">
    ssf
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dfy59/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

As already said in others answers, the nth-child selector counts childs, and that's all; you can do anything to change that.
You can take the div that causes the problems outside of the first level childs, as has already been said.

If this is a problem, an alternative is to change that element to another type that is not **div**. Then, you can use **div:nth-of-type(even)** that only counts divs.

One way of the other, you need to change in some way your DOM.